# HighCharts does not recognize a function of Legend

Tags: angular, highcharts

so I have a chart where I need to change the name of the legend after the chart has been created I am using

```
this.chart.legend.allItems[i].update({name: ''})
this.chart.redraw()
```

but I receive this error:

```
Property 'allItems' does not exist on type 'LegendObject'.
```

even though it's mentioned in the documentation and on implementation it works as needed but I can't deploy my changes b/c it catches the above error. why is angular throwing this errro?

Comment: your error and the variable name is contradicting is it allItems or allItem?

Comment: allItems* I'll fix the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have no idea why Angular throwing that error. Could you attach the content of `this.chart.legend` object?

However, I suggest you use official **Highcharts wrapper for Angular** (that can be downloaded here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular) because updating chart beyond the Angular framework is **not recommended**. Then you can just change chart options with changed legend name and change the `updateFromInput` flag to update the whole chart component. Check the code and demo posted below.

**app.module.ts :**

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { HighchartsChartModule } from "highcharts-angular";
import { ChartComponent } from "./chart.component";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ChartComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HighchartsChartModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**chart.component.html :**

```
<div class="boxChart__container">
  <div>
    <highcharts-chart
      id="container"
      [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
      [constructorType]="chartConstructor"
      [options]="chartOptions"
      [callbackFunction]="chartCallback"
      [(update)]="updateFromInput"
      [oneToOne]="true"
      style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"
    >
    </highcharts-chart>

    <button (click)="update_chart()">Change legend name</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**chart.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import * as HighchartsMore from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
import * as HighchartsExporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";

HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);

@Component({
  selector: "app-chart",
  templateUrl: "./chart.component.html"
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "app";
  chart;
  updateFromInput = false;
  Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartConstructor = "chart";
  chartCallback;
  chartOptions = {
    series: [
      {
        name: "Series name",
        data: [1, 2, 3, 6, 9]
      }
    ],
    exporting: {
      enabled: true
    },
    yAxis: {
      allowDecimals: false,
      title: {
        text: "Data"
      }
    }
  };

  constructor() {
    const self = this;

    this.chartCallback = chart => {
      self.chart = chart;
    };
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  update_chart() {
    const self = this,
      chart = this.chart;

    self.chartOptions.legend = {
      labelFormatter: function() {
        return `${this.name} - edited`;
      }
    };

    self.updateFromInput = true;
  }
}
```

**Demo:** 
https://codesandbox.io/s/7y5j93l2rq

**Highcharts Angular wrapper:** 
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Comment: I didn't know an angular wrapper existed I found a work around for my problem but I'll take a look at this as well. Thank you